# Playframework will not return custom error page

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to implement a custom error response from the global object:

```
 override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = {
    Logger("secure exceptions").logger.error(s"unhandled exception ${ex.getMessage}")
    Future.successful(Ok(ex.getCause.toString))
  }
```

The error message gets logged but I do not get the reply with curl.

How do I return my custom error message?

Comment: What do you get in the response?

Comment: Two things are irritating here. First is the `Ok(...)`, Ok returns a 200 http code is this behaviour intended in the onError handler? Second thing is the getCause. Not every exception hast a wrapped cause so this `ex.getCause.toString` might be empty which explains why you dont see a result when you curl your page. I think that curl does hide requests that return http responses with statuscode 200 by default. Try to add the -v parameter to your curl statement. Have u tried `ex.getMessage` as input parameter for your Ok Result?

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I obviously tried all of your suggestions prior to posting this. 200 will never be masked so I am using this code. InternalServerError etc' will not return anything either. 

I also explicitly wrote the message gets logged but is not returned.

Comment: Can you try to change ex.getCause.toString with e.getMessage

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure the global object is named correctly, is an object and is used? (tend to forget about the object part every now and then)

Comment: I get the log but not the response